# Reminder time & date matching

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am creating a reminder to match the date and time from user input. I can get the current date and time by using a `Timer` and `ScriptManager`. But I have no idea on how I should compare the date and time with the user input and make the label below visible after they are matched. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Reminder : System.Web.UI.Page
{

private void UpdateTimer()
{
    LabelCurrentTime.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTimer();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentdate = LabelCurrentDate.Text;
    string currenttime = LabelCurrentTime.Text;

    string reminderdate = TextBoxReminderDate.Text;
    string remindertime = TextBoxReminderTime.Text;

    Timer1.Enabled = true;

    LabelCurrentTime.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    LabelCurrentDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();

    if (currentdate == reminderdate)
    {
        if (currenttime == remindertime)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
}
}
```

Here is the screenshot :
[screenshot](http://s14.postimage.org/ixaiyk4rl/Capture.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to deal with dates as strings.  You shouldn't do that.

First off, you shouldn't accept the date as user input from a `Textbox`.  There's a specific `DateTimePicker` control specifically for having a user select a date.  You should use that.

If you use the date picker for the user to provide a date then you can get the current date using `DateTime.Now`.  Now that you have two real dates you can compare them using the `>` operator.

Comment: Hi Servy, I couldn't find DateTimePicker control in my toolbox

Comment: @Ching Hmm...it appears that the one I'm using is specific to another framework I'm using, it's not native ASP.  You could find a 3rd party implementation (Google shows several) if you want.  Another option is to parse the date from the textbox to a string using `DateTime.ParseExact` but to ensure that you don't convert the current time to a string and parse it; just use the current time from `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: How should I parse the date using DateTime.ParseExact? Sorry I'm still beginner to this. Can you show me some example on how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the documentation of the method, it has lots of examples.  Failing that, do some searches on the web as it's a highly discussed topic.  Failing that, post another question on SO with the code you're using to try to parse the string, and a detailed description of what is and isn't working.

Comment: Hi Servy, I found out that I was doing this in web site. I can find the DateTimePicker in web form application but not in web site project.

Answer (score 1):

Parse your date and time like this:

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse(currentDate+" "+currentTime);
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse(reminderDate+" "+reminderTime);
```

Then you use the [DateTime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) method to compare your DateTime objects.

Consider the following:

```
var val = DateTime.Compare(dt,dt2);
```

If val is 0 the dates and times are the same. If val is more than 0, currentDate has passed reminderDate and if val is less than zero, currentDate is before reminderDate.

Comment: You shouldn't take your times, convert them to strings, parse them, and then compare them again.  You should just keep them as datetime values from the start.

Comment: Absolutely agree, but in the example that is exactly what he is trying to do. I´m simply providing a simple answer, although not correct from a design perspective it still works.

Comment: And so you should tell him not to do that, rather than helping him to correctly implement an improper approach.  If you don't help him fix the underlying approach he won't even know it's a bad idea.  Also, to compare the dates you can just use the `>` or `<` operators, you usually don't need to use `Compare`.